# Как применить к разным значениям в одном столбце соответствующие данные из другого?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть фрейм данных:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'words': ['a|b|c|d','a|b','b|d|a','d|b'], 'numbs': [3, 4, 5,6]})
```

Как посчитать сумму `numbs` для каждой буквы, например, 'a' есть в первой, второй и третьей ячейке соответственно, a = 3 + 4 + 5?

Comment: @MaxU а что с ними можно делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res =  (df
        .assign(word=df["words"].str.split("|"))
        .explode("word")
        .groupby("word")
        ["numbs"]
        .sum())
```

результат:

```
In [79]: res
Out[79]: 
word
a    12
b    18
c     3
d    14
Name: numbs, dtype: int64
```